# OnTouchListerner is not working

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

```
package com.manish;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class GFXSurface1 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{


    MyGameSurface ourSurfaceView;
    float x,y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ourSurfaceView = new MyGameSurface(this);
        ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        x=0;
        y=0;
        setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSurfaceView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        ourSurfaceView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        return true;
    }

    public class MyGameSurface1 extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
        Thread ourThread = null;
        boolean isRunning= false;

        public MyGameSurface1(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context);
            ourHolder = getHolder();


        }

        public void pause(){
            isRunning= false;
            while(true){
                try {
                    ourThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            ourThread= null;
        }
        public void resume(){
            isRunning= true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         while(isRunning){
             if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                 continue;

             Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
             canvas.drawRGB(5,5,100);
             if(x != 0 && y !=  0){
                 Bitmap test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.selected);
                 canvas.drawBitmap(test, x-(test.getWidth()/2), y-(test.getHeight()/2), null);
             }
             ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

         }
        }

    }

}
```

OnTouchListen is not working
According to the code,
If I touch the screen, a image should be there (obviously which I selected), but there is response when I touch my phone screen.
No errors are shown by eclipse

Comment: You haven't written any thing in your onTouch() method.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code fot `onTouch()`

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your touchlistener before you are placing your layout:

```
ourSurfaceView = new MyGameSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x=0;
    y=0;
```

I guess you are developing a game but it should probably be after setcontentview.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only getting x and y value inside `onTouch()` method thats why it is not responding.

Try to use `run()` method code inside `onTouch()` method